# How do I get the expected width and height of an unrendered element?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a canvas in which I want to draw 16 vertical lines across it. The canvas also sits on top of a user control element called TimeLine. If I create lines manually in XAML they are visible on top of the user control so that's not the issue. The lines are created programmatically and stored in an ObservableCollection which is bound to the ItemsControl. Since I want all lines to have the same spacing between each other (and I specifically want 16 lines) I'm using the *ActualWidth* property of the canvas. However, it seems that my line-creating method runs before the canvas is rendered so the ActualWidth returns a null (I think, while debugging it just says Not a Number), and therefore my lines get a length of 0 and are not visible. Is there any way I can wait for the canvas to render or to get notified when the size changes? I don't want to use specific pixel amounts because I need a responsive layout.

I tried setting the *DrawTimeLineGridLines()* as the event handler of the page's *Loaded* event but that didn't do anything.

**XAML**

```xml
<local:TimeLine Grid.Row="1" Background="LightGray" x:Name="timeLine" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" />

<ItemsControl x:Name="gridCanvas" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TimeLineGridLines}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line X1="{Binding From.X}" Y1="{Binding From.Y}" X2="{Binding To.X}" Y2="{Binding To.Y}" Stroke="DarkBlue" StrokeThickness="3" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

**MyCustomLine**

```cs
class MyCustomLine
    {
        public Point From { get; set; }
        public Point To { get; set; }
        public Brush Brush { get; set; }
        public double StrokeThickness { get; set; }

    }
```

**Viewmodel**

```cs
private ObservableCollection<MyCustomLine> gridLines = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomLine>();

public ObservableCollection<MyCustomLine> TimeLineGridLines
        {
            get { return gridLines; }
            set
            {
                if (gridLines != value)
                {
                    gridLines = value;
                    OnPropertyChange();
                }
            }
        }
```

**XAML.cs**

```cs
private void DrawTimeLineGridLines()
        {
            var gridLines = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomLine>();
            double horizontalSpacing = gridCanvas.Width / 15;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                var line = new MyCustomLine()
                {
                    From = new Point(horizontalSpacing * i, 0),
                    To = new Point(horizontalSpacing * i, gridCanvas.Height),
                    Brush = Brushes.DarkBlue,
                    StrokeThickness = 5,
                };

                gridLines.Add(line);
            }

            viewmodel.TimeLineGridLines = gridLines;
        }
```

Desired result is to draw vertical lines onto a canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XAML draws a set of vertical lines without any manual size or location calculations:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="3" Fill="DarkBlue"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Sample DataContext:

```
DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 16);
```

---

You may perhaps want to draw `n` items with `n-1` lines in order to get evenly spaced gaps on the left and right edge. To achieve that, make the Rectangle left-aligned and do not draw the first one:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" AlternationCount="1000000">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="3" Fill="DarkBlue"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-1.5,0,0,0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, that was one of the things I was trying to figure out. But I'd really like dashed lines. So I tried replacing the data template with a line but it doesn't draw them? I'll try to do a border on the rectangle in the data template and see if it works out.

Comment: Just use a very long Line, e.g. `<Line Y2="10000" Stroke="DarkBlue" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeDashArray="2,2"/>`